# Why do programming languages have both double and float?

Tags: programming-languages, theory

I know that doubles are more precise than floats and that they should be used for financial stuff and other things that require precision, but why do we use floats? Why not just get rid of floats and use doubles for everything since they're more accurate?

Sorry, if this should've been asked somewhere else. I feel like only posts that contain code should go to stack overflow and I didn't know where else to ask this.

Comment: It might [interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329613/decimal-vs-double-speed). Note that, unless programming languages are focused on a specific field, they have to provide with a wide range of resources to cover all sort of developments. For all sort of fields, needs and requirements and constraints. In other words, programming languages try to be as versatile as possible.

Comment: see also [When do you use float and when do you use double](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/188721/31260)

Comment: Also related: [Why are floats still part of the Java language when doubles are mostly recommended instead?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316822/why-are-floats-still-part-of-the-java-language-when-doubles-are-mostly-recommend). It's about Java, but much of the information there is applicable to most languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doubles take twice more space. On some devices and for some applications this makes a difference. Think of 3D graphics: lots of numbers and no need for super-accurate results.

Also, financial transactions use integers (think dollars and cents) because they need not just accuracy, but exactness.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but we still use floats because somethings like 3D graphics don't need the extra precision and your literally using half as much memory by using floats instead of doubles.

Comment: This would also probably be the reason Rust has 32 and 64 but float types, but no double type.

Comment: This answer would be improved by mentioning that the issue with increased size is not memory _per se_ but _speed_. The primary reason for wanting to use less memory is that it makes processing faster.

Comment: @DavidArno: The CPU is not doing the processing of 3D graphics on modern hardware; the GPU is. The major bottleneck is in the transfer of data from CPU to GPU. Additionally, even with process that are run on CPU, the major slowdown on almost every process is cache-miss, and cache-misses are less common with more compact data.

Comment: @DavidArno, did you read both the answer and the comments on that link? Because it would seem the comments break down the answer.

Comment: @AdamOates Rust's `f64` type *is* Rust's `double` type. From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#floating-point-types): *"Floating-point numbers are represented according to the IEEE-754 standard. The f32 type is a single-precision float, and f64 has double precision."*